# updater function with air framework

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

this is for flash CS6 AS3 AIR

Seriously I've been searching for 3 days straight 
found these among others.
http://gregsramblings.com/2008/08/16/adding-auto-update-features-to-your-air-application-in-3-easy-steps/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html

but they all output errors like `Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 2  1172: Definition air.update.events:UpdateEvent could not be found.` not all have this specific error but they all have a definition error. Apart from that they are doing a lot of things in the tutorial that I simply don't need.

I already made a version detector and right now it's downloading the air file to the desktop but I need something more practical. is there  something like `updatenTo(http://address.com/myApp.air)` - which just start the air updateframework to update from the .air file at the refered address.

or even a download command that tells me where the user downloaded the file to so I can execute the file and terminate the program. like `file.addEventListener(Event.locationOfDownload,downloadFileContainFunction);`

or link me to a tutorial that has working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my problem here actually boiled down to finding "applicationupdater.swc" and how to import it.

It's found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\AIR3.2\frameworks\libs\air" on my machine

One can import it by going to "publish settings" and click the wrench key next to "script: ActionScript 3.0" and going to the library path clicking the little red f on white background.

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that you haven't imported the class or embedded the library you are trying to use.